# Image not shown with in my project react native

Tags: react-native

I am starting React Native and working with Visual Studio Code.

Image Component not working, I did like this but background image not shown.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, StyleSheet, TouchableOpacity, Text, Dimensions, Image} from 'react-native';
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/Ionicons';
import GLOBAL from '../../global';
import I18n from '../../i18n'

var { width, height } = Dimensions.get('window');

export default class EsseGroupScreen extends Component {

  render() {
    return(
      <View style = {styles.container}>
        {this.renderHeader()}
        <Image source={require('../../assets/esse_group_back.png')} style={styles.imgBack} />
      </View>
    )
  }

  renderHeader() {
    return(
        <View style={styles.header}>
        </View>
    )
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flexDirection: 'column',
    backgroundColor: 'white'
  },
  imgBack: {      
    flex: 1,
    alignSelf: 'stretch',
    width: width,
    height: height-50,
    resizeMode: 'contain'
  }
});
```

I tried many cases but can't find clear answer.

```
<Image source={require('../../assets/esse_group_back.png')} style={styles.imgBack} />
```

Above code is not working, who please help me.

My dependencies are following.

```
"dependencies": {
    "react": "^16.8.6",
    "react-native": "^0.60.0",
    "react-native-grid-view": "https://github.com/lucholaf/react-native-grid-view.git",
    "react-native-i18n": "^2.0.15",
    "react-native-numeric-input": "^1.8.0",
    "react-native-scalable-image": "https://github.com/ihor/react-native-scalable-image.git",
    "react-native-tabbar-bottom": "^1.0.4",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^6.6.0",
    "react-navigation": "https://github.com/Maxeh/react-navigation.git",
    "rn-viewpager": "https://github.com/zbtang/React-Native-ViewPager.git"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.5.0",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.5.2",
    "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "^0.0.5",
    "babel-jest": "^24.8.0",
    "eslint": "^6.0.1",
    "jest": "^24.8.0",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "^0.55.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "^16.8.6"
  },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is simple.

You can use ImageBackground component instead of Image

```
<ImageBackground source={require('../../assets/esse_group_back.png')} style={styles.imgBack} />
```

Also import ImageBackground from react-native

```
import { View, StyleSheet, TouchableOpacity, Text, Dimensions, ImageBackground} from 'react-native';
```

Comment: I found another answer, the reason is flex:1 in style of Image. After I remove it, it works well though I use Image component.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is with your path of image. You are giving an incorrect path to image source. I tried your code with my image folder and it works fine. Just check the image path and replace with correct path.

Comment: EsseGroupScreen located in "src/components/about/company.js" folder and image path is "src/assets/esse_group_back.png" so I think the path is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Considering your folder structure like this,

```
--project
  --src folder
    --assets folder
      --esse_group_back.png file
    --Some folder
      --EsseGroupScreen.js file
    --App.js file
    --index.js file
```

You can do this,

```
<Image source={require('../assets/esse_group_back.png')} style={styles.imgBack} /> //If your folder stucture something else try to change path, here `..` means parent folder of file
```

Or more simplified,

```
import esse_group_back from '../assets/esse_group_back.png'; //If your folder stucture something else try to change path, here `..` means parent folder of file

<Image source={esse_group_back} style={styles.imgBack} />
```

Answer (score -1):

use the code

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {Dimensions,Image, StyleSheet, Text, View} from 'react-native';
var { width, height } = Dimensions.get('window');


export default class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text style={styles.welcome}>Welcome to React Native!</Text>
        <Image source={require('./assets/image/find.png')} style={styles.imgBack} />

      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flexDirection: 'column',
    backgroundColor: 'white'
  },
  welcome: {
    fontSize: 20,
    textAlign: 'center',
    margin: 10,
  },
  imgBack: {
    tintColor:'red',
    alignSelf: 'stretch',
    width: width,
    height: height-50,
    resizeMode: 'contain'
  },
});
```

Comment: `./path_to_file` mean the file/folder is in same folder.